# Is there a use case for an alternative "exception cause" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

## Background

In Python it is possible to suppress the context of an `Exception` if you raise your Exception `from None`. [PEP 409](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0409/) describes the rationale behind it. Sometimes you want to show only one meaningful (custom) Exception. With [PEP 415](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0415/) the implementation changes with the following argument:

> The main problem with this scheme [from PEP 409] is it complicates the role of __cause__. __cause__ should indicate the cause of the exception not whether __context__ should be printed or not. This use of __cause__ is also not easily extended in the future. For example, we may someday want to allow the programmer to select which of __context__ and __cause__ will be printed.

## Question

PEP 419 talks about future use cases. Are there any valid use cases right now (Python 3.3+) for using an alternative exception cause? For example, consider the following code:

```py
    class CustomError(BaseException):
        pass

    class StupidError(BaseException):
        def __init__(self, message='This is just a stupid error.'):
            super(StupidError, self).__init__(message)
            self.message = message

    try:
        value = int('a')
    except Exception:
        raise CustomError('Custom error message') from StupidError
```

Output:

```
StupidError: This is just a stupid error.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last): (...)
CustomError: Custom error message
```

Are there any real use cases in which you want to hide the `ValueError` but show the `StupidError`? I mean you could give some relevant information in the `StupidError` which are not present in a mere `ValueError`? Maybe I am just overthinking this whole thing.

Comment: As a very niche example. At my last company, we had an error that would result in the same end result but could be caused by several things. So as far as the end user was concerned, we would have a unified ending, but as far as internal practices/logging we would do different things. We used the errors from other_error to handle that.

I'm sure that's not the best example, but the only one I've actually seen in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Say you're writing a web app and need to hide sensitive/complicated data from the user.

Say a user tries a request, but the web app backend has trouble reading the necessary data from a MySQL database (for whatever reason). Instead of letting the MySQL module raise the error, which could either expose sensitive information about how the app works internally or just simply confuse the user, I would want to catch it and then throw my custom exception (let's call it `serverError`). That custom exception would show the user a HTTP 500 page as well as report the error internally so it can be analyzed by a developer to figure out what went wrong and how to prevent it.

This means I only have to write my general error handling code once, and then when I catch an error, I can raise `serverError`, which takes care of the error reporting for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that it is helpful to raise a custom exception. I also understand the use case to raise the custom ServerError from None. But why would you raise raise the ServerError from another exception in your use case? Or would you raise from ServerError?

Comment: I would raise ServerError when a generic exception is caught (except Exception as e) that I didn't account for in programming, or when a specific exception that is rare, but possible (like a SQL read error). This means that the web app will fail gracefully, and the ServerError exception class can handle the reporting.